# VBScript quiz error

Tags: vbscript

I want to create a game about HTML using VBScript. Here is the code:

```
Dim args
args=inputbox("Which is correct... A: You don't need HTML to create a webpage / B: HTML is the basics on creating a website / C: We need JavaScript over HTML / D: HTML is a programming language")
If args = A Then
X=MsgBox("You are wrong! HTML is one of the languages used by web developers",0+16,"Wrong") 
ElseIf args = B Then
X=MsgBox("You are correct! HTML is the basics on creating a website. You can't use another language without HTML",0+64,"Correct") 
ElseIf args = C Then
X=MsgBox("You are wrong! That answer might quite be true with others but no. You still need to install something to use javascript only codes. And you don't need to download anything for HTML!",0+16,"Wrong") 
ElseIf args = D Then
X=MsgBox("You are wrong! Programming languages are languages you can use to create programs. Like javascript.",0+16,"Wrong") 
Else
X=MsgBox("Answer not valid! Only A or B or C or D",0+16,"Invalid") 
End If
```

It always says "Answer not valid! Only A or B or C or D" even if I placed A, B, C, or D.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare a variable to text, you need to quote the text, like this:

```
If args = "A" Then
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought it was different from Python when it comes to if statements